# Create an object based on the keys in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I am having an array of objects and I want to create another object based on their keys. For example I am having an array as

```
var arr = [{1: 36011, 2: 18320, 3: 36011, 4: 10570},
            {1: 19754, 2: 6722, 3: 19754, 4: 6699},
            {1: 15711, 2: 10039, 3: 15711, 4: 4172}]
```

and I want my result array as

```
var result = {1:[36011,19754,15711], 2:[18320,6722,10039],..}
```

I was suggested to use lodash, I am new to this so I've tried using reduce

```
var i = 1, new_arr = {};
_.reduce(arr, function(key, val){
     new_arr[i++] = temp1.key 
return new_arr;
},{})
```

I am getting the values as *undefined*. What is the mistake, Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: There is no need for lodash, reduce is widely supported. This is almost 2020! The `i` in your code is global, so it will count all the values. The reduce in your code cannot have key/val pair since you are applying it to an array.

Comment: Neither of the questions indicated in "close as duplicate" had answers to this question. Both of those were about grouping on a single, specific property, whereas this is about cross-merging multiple objects on arbitrary properties.

Answer (score 2):

This might look intimidating at first. Start reducing the dataset from an empty object. Then reduce each row starting with result of outer reduce and build on the result so far.

```js
const addToBucket = (bucket = {}, k, v, prev = bucket[k] || []) => ({
  ...bucket,
  [k]: [...prev, v],
})

const toBucket = list =>
  list.reduce(
    (bucket, row) =>
      Object.entries(row).reduce((b, [k, v]) => addToBucket(b, k, v), bucket),
    {},
  )

const data = [
  { 1: 36011, 2: 18320, 3: 36011, 4: 10570 },
  { 1: 19754, 2: 6722, 3: 19754, 4: 6699 },
  { 1: 15711, 2: 10039, 3: 15711, 4: 4172 },
]

console.log(toBucket(data))

// Nested list, as requested
console.log(Object.entries(toBucket(data)).map(([_, v]) => v))
```

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful and I learned a new piece of code today! @kornieff

Comment: Glad I could help. If my code is still scary, just read up on ES6 deconstruct and spread features. Welcome to 2020 !

Comment: If I want to create the whole in an array, not an object, How should I change it? @kornieff

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you want it to look like?

Comment: I've added an image to my question. check it @kornieff

Answer (score 2):

with lodash you can use `_.mergeWith()` and concat the values in the customiser function:

```js
const arr = [{"1":36011,"2":18320,"3":36011,"4":10570},{"1":19754,"2":6722,"3":19754,"4":6699},{"1":15711,"2":10039,"3":15711,"4":4172}]
            
const result = _.mergeWith({}, ...arr, (ov = [], sv) => ov.concat(sv))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this in simplest way.

> This is also available online at https://rextester.com/IPI35964 to try and see output.

```
var arr = [{1: 36011, 2: 18320, 3: 36011, 4: 10570},
        {1: 19754, 2: 6722, 3: 19754, 4: 6699},
        {1: 15711, 2: 10039, 3: 15711, 4: 4172}]

var output = {}
for(var obj of arr){
    for(var key in obj){
        if(key in output){
            output[key].push(obj[key])
        } else {
            output [key] = [obj[key]]
        }
    }
}
console.log(output)
```

> Output

```
{ '1': [ 36011, 19754, 15711 ],
  '2': [ 18320, 6722, 10039 ],
  '3': [ 36011, 19754, 15711 ],
  '4': [ 10570, 6699, 4172 ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

One fairly clean way of doing this:

- Create one big array of key-value pairs
- Group those key-value pairs by their keys
- Extract the values from the grouped key-value pairs

```js
var arr = [
  { 1: 36011, 2: 18320, 3: 36011, 4: 10570 },
  { 1: 19754, 2: 6722, 3: 19754, 4: 6699 },
  { 1: 15711, 2: 10039, 3: 15711, 4: 4172 }
];

// Get one big array of all key-value pairs
var pairs = _.flatMap(arr, _.entries);

// Group by the keys (index 0 of the pairs)
var groups = _.groupBy(pairs, 0);

// Extract the values
var final = _.mapValues(groups, _.partial(_.map, _, 1));

//console.log(pairs);
console.log(final);


// Using chaining:
var final2 = _.chain(arr)
  .flatMap(_.entries)
  .groupBy(0)
  .mapValues(_.partial(_.map, _, 1));

console.log(final2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```