# How to combine list of dictionaries in Javascript into a nested dictionary?

Tags: javascript, list, dictionary, object, nested

I am new to Javascript and I have question very similar to [How to combine multiple dictionaries in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168283/how-to-combine-multiple-dictionaries-in-javascript)

Except that I want to achieve a nested dictionary.

```
var dictA = {gender: 'male', age_group: 'young', favourite_band: 'Metallica', number_of_visits: 42};
var dictB = {gender: 'female', age_group: 'old', favourite_band: 'Beatles', number_of_visits: 2};
var dictC = {gender: 'male', age_group: 'young', favourite_band: 'Foo Fighters', number_of_visits: 1};
var dictD = {gender: 'male', age_group: 'old', favourite_band: 'Rolling Stones', number_of_visits: 12};
```

Expected Outcome:

```
var result = 
   {
     'male': {
              'young': {'Metallica': 42, 'Foo Fighters': 1},
              'old': {'Rolling Stones': 12}
             },
     'female': {'old': {'Beatles': 2}}

   }
```

Possibly there is even one more nested information. Is this somehow achieveable?
I appreciate every help!

Edit: that example is only showing how it’s done for one „layer“. How can I for example provide a list of „layer columns“ and achieve what’s done above?